# How to set a counter to double the value of another counter?

Tags: counters, calculations

The title says it. Lets have to counters:

```
\newcounter{myCount}
\newcounter{anotherCount}
```

I set `myCount` to some value for example `10`

```
\setcounter{myCount}{10}
```

How do I set counter `anotherCount` to double the value of `myCount`? I have tried things like

```
\setcounter{anotherCount}{2\value{myCount}}
```

and

```
\setcounter{anotherCount}{2\themyCount}
```

but non of this works.

Comment: `\multiply\myCount by 2` — this is not a length!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The 'official' LaTeX way (using only things documented in *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System*) is to use `\addtocounter`, as mentioned in a comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{A}{3}
\setcounter{B}{\value{A}}
\addtocounter{B}{\value{A}}

\arabic{A} and \arabic{B}
\end{document}
```

Loading the `calc` package (part of the core LaTeX2e system) allows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{A}{3}
\setcounter{B}{2*\value{A}}

\arabic{A} and \arabic{B}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can also use lower-level TeX or e-TeX constructs, as covered in the other answers.

Comment: the "official LaTeX" way was defined _before_ eTeX was developed with  its  `\numexpr` and `\dimexpr`

Comment: @Herbert Of course. The `\numexpr` primitive does not have LaTeX syntax, so really doesn't fit 'properly'. One could of course redefine `\setcounter` to use e-TeX, in a similar way to the way that `calc` alters the definitions to allow expressions in a very different way. (Or you could use Heiko's `intcalc` package for the same thing without requiring e-TeX.)

Comment: For me calc syntax is simplest and looks consistent with LaTeX counters.

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{A}    \newcounter{B}
\setcounter{A}{3} \setcounter{B}{\numexpr\theA*2\relax}

\theA\ and \theB

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget that counter isn't same as length. Use commands `\advance`, `\divide` and `\multiply` to work with counters.

For example, this code will compute value of typographics sheets (run it in the end of document):

```
\newcount{\podp}
\newcount{\podpfr}
\podp=\c@page
\podpfr=\c@page
\divide\podp by 16
\multiply\podp by 100
\multiply\podpfr by 100
\divide\podpfr by 16
\advance\podpfr by -\podp
\divide\podp by 100
…
\hbox to 0pt{Формат $60\!\times\!84\;1/16$}\hfil Усл.печ.л.~%
{\the\podp.\ifnum\podpfr<10 0\fi\the\podpfr}\hfil
```

Comment: LaTeX is just a set of macros on TeX, so I see nothing awful to use tex in latex.

Comment: In simple things like this there's better to use tex commands whether to use one more latex package that do such simple work. If such thins meets frequently in document, there would be better to choose latex-way.